# Ubuntu file system corruption error won't boot

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

my digital ocean droplet is going through some tough errors and I can't find any help. Perhaps someone here could point me the way.

I was using the droplet normally, after running a failed DeployBot job with the following error message: cannot create directory ‘..../releases/1443221387’
output : Read-only file system

I then logged in my droplet with the root user and tried to create a simple text file, got the same error message: "Read-only file system".

So I restarted the droplet, which rendered it inacessible through SSH (connection time out). When I log in through Digital Ocean's console access, it gives me the following error screen:

[image]

I contacted digital ocean's support and they told me that a physical error is highly unlikely cause they haven't had any tickets for the same type of error in this machine.

I'm truly losing my sleep because of this, only weeks away from my web app launch, and can't figure this out. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: did you installed some updates?

Comment: I didn't.. Both times this happened it was running normally.

Answer (score 0):

Don't get bothered about the EXT4-fs error count. It is sort of a statistic about the occured errors. A fsck of the unmounted filesystem (e.g. from a rescue media) and a clean reboot should fix that. Digital Ocean describes the process here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-recover-from-file-system-corruption-using-fsck-and-a-recovery-iso

The main issue seems to be duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788358/process-plymouth-upstart-bridge-keeps-terminating